# How can I fix this potential infinite loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, factorial

This code for the factorize problem gives "potential infinite loop" bug.

```
function factorialize(num) {
  for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
     num *= (num - i);
  }
  return num;
}
```

Please help me to explain if possible.

Comment: You're looping from `1 to num` but also changing `num` inside the loop.

Comment: Just use another variable, for example factorial, initialize it with value 1 and do factorial *= num; inside your loop and return it. To optimize your code you can start from loop from 2 in this case

Comment: What do you mean by "potential infinite loop bug"? Do you see this in an online submission system, or an error/warning message?

Answer (score 1):

> My potential solution for this factorize problem gives "potential
>   infinite loop" bug. please help me to explain if possible.

Because you are increasing the value of `num` and `i` is never going to be greater than or equal to `num` in this case.

Initialize a new variable

```
function factorialize(num) {
  var result = 1; 
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
     result *= (i);
  }
  return result;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function factorialize(num) {
  var result = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    result *= (i);
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(factorialize(3));
console.log(factorialize(4));
console.log(factorialize(5));
```